# What is this animated image and how is it created?

Tags: image, animation, graphics

I was wondering what these animated images (like the ones on this site:
https://tenlor.com/how-it-works) are called and how to make them? Thanks so much!

Comment: Right-click on the image and save or open in a new window, etc, and all will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

Hovering over it (or tap and hold on mobile devices) shows you it is a simple GIF.

Google 'GIF' to understand how to make them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for the page you linked to, those animated images are `.gif`s, which stands for Graphics Interchange Format and is a bitmap image format.

If you want to create GIFs, there are lots of ways to do this, depending on the source material you want to create from, your level of technical ability and the tools you already have available to you.

As a starting point though, take a look at [makeagif](http://makeagif.com/).